# Using both FastLED and Webserver without glitches possible?

Tags: esp8266, web-server, neopixel

I'm using an ESP8266 to control a short strip of WS2812 LEDs. I also want some way of remote Control so I'm looking into using a Web UI with the ESPAsyncWebServer library.

However using that Webserver makes the LEDs flicker so I tried disabling Interrupts

```
#define FASTLED_ALLOW_INTERRUPTS 0
#define FASTLED_INTERRUPT_RETRY_COUNT 2
```

That does help a bit, the flickering is less frequent but now there's some color glitches aswell.
All in all not usable.

So is there a way to get rid of all that flickering or is it just not possible to use the LEDs and a Webserver together when maintaining a high refresh rate?

Comment: might try websockets instead of http. the client code is about as simple and the "requests" tend to execute much faster without all the http overhead. you can also use a 2nd ESP to do web, talking to the LED ESP via serial, which is buffered and also low-impact.

Comment: Alternatively upgrading to a dual-core ESP32 would remove the problem and give you a more capable chip into the bargain...